# Объявление двумерного массива java

Tags: java, массивы

Друзья, помогите, пожалуйста, с таким вопросом. Встретил такой кусок кода в Java

```
public String saveComputingResult(int firstNumber, int secondNumber, String operation) {
    String[][] arr = new String[2][0]; //**
    arr[0] = new String[1]; //**
    arr[1] = new String[1]; //**
    arr[0][0] = getOperation(operation);
    arr[1][0] = Integer.toString(getComputingResult(firstNumber, secondNumber, operation));
    return arr[0][0] + " - " + arr[1][0];
```

Кто может пояснить выделенные комментарием `//**` строки? Объявляется двумерный массив типа String, имеет две строки и....0!!! столбцов. Это как? Что это означает? В Шилдте и Эккеле таких примеров нету, есть только примеры где размер массива указывается для первого массива, так как это обязательно, а второй [] просто остается пустым, но что означает если там 0 внутри? 
И что означают эти строки при этом??

```
arr[0] = new String[1];
arr[1] = new String[1];
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объявляется массив состоящий из двух массивов нулевой длины.
То есть каждый элемент массива имеет указатель на физический адрес, где хранится массив нулевой длины.

При объявлении:

```
String[][] arr = new String[2][];
```

каждому элементу массива присвоено значение **null** вместо указателя на адрес, то есть:

```
arr[0]=null;
arr[1]=null;
```

В вашем же случае:

```
String[][] arr = new String[2][0];
```

тоже самое что:

```
 String[][] arr = new String[2][];
    arr[0] = new String[0];
    arr[1] = new String[0];
```

Массивы нулевой длины объявлены и хранятся в памяти, а `arr[0]` и `arr[1]` присвоены указатели на адреса в памяти.

Comment: А зачем вообще так делать? Какой смысл в этом? Почему просто не написать String[][] array = new String [2][1];array [0][0] = getOperation(operation);array[1][0] = Integer.toString(getResult(input1,input2,operation));

Comment: А кто сказал что так делать правильно? Способ объявления в вашем примере лишь добавляет работы сборщику мусора. Несомненно логичнее и правильнее: `String[][] array = new String [2][1];`

Comment: Тоесть вот так лучше? String[][] array = new String [2][1];

Comment: Да, лучше. 
Кстати, если при запуске программы в командной строке не передается никаких аргументов, параметру `args`, в методе `main`, присваивается массив нулевой длины. Вот как минимум одно применение.

Comment: Спасибо, Алексей!

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1067158/3212712) и здравому смыслу при записи

```
String[][] arr = new String[2][0];
```

мы получаем массив из 2 массивов типа `String` с нулевой длинной.

Далее в приведённом вами коде ячейки массива заполняются новыми массивами с одной ячейкой в каждой:

```
arr[0] = new String[1];
arr[1] = new String[1];
```

При этом, т.к. ячейки не инициализированы, то

```
if(arr[1][0]==null) System.out.println("NULL!!!111one");
```

выведет **NULL!!!111one**

Таким образом, при последующем присваивании ячейкам элементов массива `arr` других массивов ставить им длину равную 0 (или любой другой цифре) смысла, в общем, не имеет.

Comment: Спасибо, Юрий!!